# How we can redirect any request to same page excepting one using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to redirect request on same page by excepting one page by using .htaccess file. The code that i have used

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

Dose anyone know how i can take condition on a single page named "register.php"? Means i want to open register.php now its open index.php.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.php|register\.php)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php? [L,R=301,E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Comment: hey thanks for reply .. but if i used your code then site went down & if i used you condition in my code (RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index.php|register.php)$) then it seems like same as before

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index|register)\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|raw)|[^.]*)$ index.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

Comment: What URI did you test with?

Comment: can we meet in any chat room here ?

Comment: sorry I need to be in a meeting for an hour then I will be free to chat

Comment: Ok thanks mate for your support .. is any idea whats going wrong with it ?

Comment: I think there is some disconnect in your requirements and in my interpretations :( I will come back to it in an hour.

Comment: I'm back, can you tell me when you visit `register.php` what is your full URL?

Comment: When I opened `https://shipsus.com/register.php` it opened fine. Can you pls tell me what problem you're facing with this page?

Comment: yes when we opened https://shipsus.com/register.php in url it shows https://shipsus.com/register.php but content show of index page not showing the actual register form . that's the issue

Comment: Alright if you comment out first 4 lines in the above .htaccess and then visit `https://shipsus.com/register.php` does it work then?

Comment: when i comment the first 4 line then it show same Index page content on register page .. i really can't understand whats going wrong with it

Comment: Well now you can see that. Even if you commented this suggested .htaccess code your `register.php` still showed `index.php`. So something is controlling this behavior outside .htaccess

Comment: Yes but when i changed RewriteRule (.*) index.php to RewriteRule (.*) register.php then it shows register form on all pages of the site .. let me change it please take a look

Comment: You need to figure out first why `index.php` is shown when browser is requesting `register.php`